# My question was closed and I don't understand why

Tags: support, specific-question, closing-questions

My question was marked as a duplicate but the question that's been linked is asking something different so I don't understand why

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/127049/any-direct-tranlations-from-gallifreyan

Answer (score -1):

I marked it as closed (as dupe) because two key points in KutuluMike's [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103379/20774) address the question you've asked;

> **River Song explicitly mentions that High Gallifreyan writing "doesn't
>   translate"**

and

> ... there have been many attempts by fans to scour the episodes
>   looking for hints as to what certain words might mean, based on the
>   writing in various places where The Doctor may have read or explained
>   them.
>
> ... as far as I know **the writing on the show itself is just random
>   cool-looking circular designs.**

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't one of the close-voters, but their reason for voting to close your question was probably because [the highest-voted answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/103379/31394) to the older question says:

> As far as I know, there isn't any *official* translation of the alphabet; in fact, in at least one case ("A Good Man Goes To War") River Song explicitly mentions that High Gallifreyan writing "doesn't translate" -- even the TARDIS can't do it for someone who doesn't read it.
>
> However, there have been many attempts by fans to scour the episodes looking for hints as to what certain words might mean, based on the writing in various places where The Doctor may have read or explained them.

Which also seems to answer your question, albeit not very conclusively.

Comment: I assume the answers here were downvoted by people who disagree with the closing of the question (which personally I also disagreed with, but not strongly enough to vote to leave it open) - and yet it has no votes to reopen?

Comment: It's an odd one. Perhaps they just don't like you?